# Make a custom cell fit in a Group style table's margins

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have created a custom cell that I use a lot in an application.  Its simply 2 labels.  One on the left side and one on the right.

I am attempting to use this cell for a grouped table.  However the problem is this table fills most of the screen(on an ipad) so the margins are actually wide enough they are actually reaching the text on the left and right sides.  Due to the fact that the cell itself stretches the whole length of the table, and not inside the margins.

How can I get my custom cell to fit inside the margins?

Here is my cell declaration currently..

```
static NSString *CellWithIdentifier = @"SettingsTableCell";
SettingsTableCell *settingsCell = (SettingsTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
if (settingsCell == nil)
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingsTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    settingsCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

settingsCell.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth || UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin); //my attempt to fix margin issue
settingsCell.leftText.text = val1;
settingsCell.rightText.text = val2;

return settingsCell;
```

Comment: do you override layout subviews in the cell class?

Comment: No, does that mean i should or should not override the subviews?

Comment: What I mean is its common to override the method `-(void)layoutSubviews` and forget to call super and that makes grouped table view cells look like standard ones. You might like to post a screenshot of the undesirable effect so we can see what you mean.